# Load Kotlin/Native shared library in Kotlin/JVM

Tags: kotlin, shared-libraries, interop, kotlin-native

Is there any way relative simple to load Kotlin/Native dynamic library into Kotlin/JVM. Some details of my case: I have some Kotlin/JVM interface for example `IGenerator`:

```
interface IGenerator {
   fun generate(): ByteArray
}
```

and I want to implement this interface using native code due to performance purpose. Without Kotlin/Native I would wrote a C/C++ code then compile it into shared library and build a JVM wrapper using for example SWIG (http://www.swig.org/). This tool generate JNI wrapper for my shared library and it'll be good to load into my Kotlin/JVM app.

So the question: is there a convenient way to load Kotlin/Native shared library into Kotlin/JVM application? I'd like to use any sort of Kotlin tooling without creation of separated wrappers or any other voodoo magic.

Comment: I'm afraid that it does not work as you wish. Kotlin/Native can be compiled to the shared library, but it will lead to the same wrapping as with C/C++. If you want to use native, you got to write in Kotlin/Native, using its compiler to produce binaries. Also, you'd be able to share some logic between native code and JVM code.  For this reason, there is a Multiplatform plugin, that is described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html). But also I got to mention that currently Kotlin/Native isn't ready to show extraordinal performance, as it is still in Beta.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gradle, it's simple enough (:shared is Kotlin/Native Multiplatform project):

```
implementation project(':shared')
```

You can then use any K/N method written in `:shared` in your Kotlin/JVM project.