# Is it possible to package Kotlin Native executables (for different platforms) in a JAR file and also include a JVM implementation as a fallback?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, packaging, kotlin-native

### Reasoning

I'm trying to include the Kotlin Native executables to lower the performance impact (in CPU time and in memory usage) of a part of my app since Kotlin Native is AOT instead of JIT, but I also want to be able to take advantage of the extreme portability of JVM on platforms where either Kotlin Native isn't supported, where I simply haven't built for that target to lower build complexity or where dependencies that the natives require.

### Ideal solution

Ideally I'd like this to be packaged all into the main JAR file that my app (written in Java) uses. For context this app revolves around real-time audio compression/decompression and networking (VoIP).

### Extra context

I'm also using Gradle (Groovy) as the build system.

### Related questions

[Load Kotlin/Native shared library in Kotlin/JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239250/load-kotlin-native-shared-library-in-kotlin-jvm) - this question appears to be slightly similar, however it doesn't cover how you'd use compile JVM code to package in as well and use as a fallback in the case of none of the natives being suitable (incorrect platform, missing dependencies etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, you are only missing the last step, explore JNI, and imagine the dynamic lib compiled by kotlin native as a c lib, you only need jni to complete your needs, but this does not belong to kotlin The problem in the native category is more inclined to the usage of jni.

When kotlin native is compiled successfully, you will get a .h file in the build directory, and a .dylib/.so file, it just depends on your platform, but if you want to use the generality of jvm, you should Compile for more than a single platform.

If you need to know more, please try some yourself first, then comment here, I will give some suggestions for some of your attempts.

Comment: Ok so I've now got one function in the kotlin native code called `add` which takes two `int`s and returns an int - this is bundled into the jar file and loaded at runtime, however, I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when trying to called `add`, since I'm guessing, by default a Kotlin Native function is set up to be exported in the way JNI wants it to be (in C this would be `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` - how would you export it that way? The full error btw is `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int uk.co.protobyter.kikennamc.JNIHandler.add(int, int)'`

Comment: Here are a few articles for your reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65661275/12346099

https://matt-moore.medium.com/kotlin-jni-for-native-code-835e93af7ddf

https://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2019/12/15/jni-kotlin/